# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). Jekyll blog doesn't seem to find assets such as css and js

Tags: css, github, http-status-code-404, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to run a Jekyll website on Github pages and after following some guidance I've found on the internet I successfully got to load the index page.
But somehow the page doesn't seem to render the css and js assets. 
I think it has something to do with the `baseurl` on `_config.yml` so I have tried many inputs on this field but none of them seem to work.

What could be wrong?

```
#
###################################
# Site wide configuration
####################################
#
title: Guilherme Atihe de Oliveira
email: atihe.guilherme@gmail.com
description: A simple and awesome blog theme powered by jekyll.
url: # the base hostname & protocol for your site
keywords: ["blog", "jekyll"]
baseurl: 'https://gatihe.github.io/blog/'

#
###################################
# Jekyll configuration
####################################
#
timezone:          Europe/Paris
markdown:          kramdown
highlighter:       rouge
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
permalink:         /articles/:year-:month/:title

kramdown:
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  enable_coderay: false

#
###################################
# Site Owner configuration
####################################
#
owner:
  name: Guilherme
  avatar: leonids-logo.png
  job: "iOS developer"
  bio: "A simple and awesome blog theme powered by jekyll."
  email:
  disqus-shortname:
  twitter: #username
  facebook: guilhermeatihe
  google:
    plus: #username
    analytics:
    verify:
    ad-client:
    ad-slot:
  bing-verify:
  github: #username
  gitlab: #username
  stackoverflow: #123456/username   from a     
"http://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/username" link
  linkedin: #username
  skype: #username
  xing: #username
  instagram: #username
  lastfm: #username
  tumblr: #username
  pinterest: #username
  foursquare: #username
  steam: #username
      dribbble: #username
      youtube: #username
      soundcloud: #username
      weibo: #username
      flickr: #username
      500px: #username
      codepen: #username
      reddit: #username
      telegram: #username
```

Comment: You should edit/remove personal info like Gmail address

Answer (score 2):

I checked your website at https://gatihe.github.io/blog/ and indeed your css URL and base URL are not matching. You're loading your main css with this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gatihe.github.io/css/main.css">
```

If you check the URL https://gatihe.github.io/css/main.css in the browser you'll get 404.

If you change the URL of your main css to be in line with your base URL, which means I added `/blog/` before `css/main.css`, so I'm using this URL https://gatihe.github.io/blog/css/main.css, I can load your css in the browser.

So, you can fix this by fixing the URL where you load your css and you can apply the same to your Javascript (https://gatihe.github.io/blog/js/main.js).